# Postfix cannot send email to own domain name from VPS

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, vps, postfix-mta

We had a shared hosting for, let's say myndd.com. then we migrated to a VPS

I installed postfix and I'm able to send emails to everyone except addresses from my own domain.

The hosting company told me it is normal because the MX zone is managed my mail01.myndd.com, so I have to forward emails to  mail01.myndd.com

Problem is if I go to /etc/postfix/main.cf  and add relayhost=mail01.myndd.com I cannot send emails to anyone anymore.

A temporary solution could be to forward our email to some others in another account like for example forward example1@myndd.com to example1@myotherndd.com  . It will help but I find it a bit dirty.

Any idea how I can handle this problem?

Thanks !

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm more of as developer and I'm a bit new to sysadmin. Please leave a comment to explain the downfall so I can improve myself for my next question....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Bad. I found a way using transport.

I had to add the following line into /etc/postfix/transport:
myndd.com        smtp:mail01.myndd.com

Tehn I launched
=> postmap /etc/postfix/transport.

Then I added the line  transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport into /etc/postfix/main.cf

then 
=> run postfix reload

So I can send emails in @myndd.com